# Tuning Slow Performing Queries

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a query which is taking too long to execute.

I used database tuning advisor to check this query and it suggested some missing indexes and statistics. The problem is I can't create missing index and statistics on those tables because it will slowdown insert/update and affect other scripts. They can't sacrifice their scripts performance because of my query.

Without the help of DTA or disturbing other scripts how do I have to tune my query? Can i break it into small pieces? If so, how?

```
INSERT INTO #val 
SELECT lid.orgid, 
       lid.periodid, 
       lid.sourceid, 
       lid.statementtypecode, 
       lid.financialsbucketid, 
       lid.statementcurrencycodeiso, 
       lid.lineitemid, 
       lll.financialconceptidglobal, 
       lid.physicalmeasureid, 
       CASE 
         WHEN EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 '1' 
                     FROM   trf.dbo.lineitemfundbdescription LIFD(nolock) 
                     WHERE  lll.orgid = lifd.orgid 
                            AND lll.lineitemid = lifd.lineitemid) THEN 
         (SELECT lifd.lineitemshortdescription 
          FROM   trf.dbo.lineitemfundbdescription LIFD(nolock) 
          WHERE  lll.orgid = lifd.orgid 
                 AND lll.lineitemid = lifd.lineitemid) 
         ELSE lll.lineitemname 
       END              AS LineItemName, 
       ( CASE 
           WHEN ( lid.reportedcurrencycodeiso IS NOT NULL 
                  AND fc.iscurrencydependent = 1 
                  AND 
           lid.statementcurrencycodeiso <> lid.reportedcurrencycodeiso 
                  AND fc.isflowitem = 1 ) THEN 
lid.lineiteminstancevalue * 
cds.dbo.Exrate(lid.reportedcurrencycodeiso, lid.statementcurrencycodeiso, p.periodenddate) 
  WHEN ( lid.reportedcurrencycodeiso IS NOT NULL 
         AND fc.iscurrencydependent = 1 
         AND lid.statementcurrencycodeiso <> lid.reportedcurrencycodeiso 
         AND fc.isflowitem = 0 
         AND p.periodlengthunitcode = 'M' ) THEN lid.lineiteminstancevalue 
* 
cds.dbo.Getaveragefxrate(lid.reportedcurrencycodeiso, lid.statementcurrencycodeiso, 
Dateadd("MONTH", -p.periodlength, p.periodenddate), p.periodenddate) 
  WHEN ( lid.reportedcurrencycodeiso IS NOT NULL 
         AND fc.iscurrencydependent = 1 
         AND lid.statementcurrencycodeiso <> lid.reportedcurrencycodeiso 
         AND fc.isflowitem = 0 
         AND p.periodlengthunitcode = 'W' ) THEN lid.lineiteminstancevalue 
* 
cds.dbo.Getaveragefxrate(lid.reportedcurrencycodeiso, lid.statementcurrencycodeiso, 
Dateadd("WEEK", -p.periodlength, p.periodenddate), p.periodenddate) 
  ELSE lid.lineiteminstancevalue 
END )            AS LineItemInstanceValue, 
( CASE 
    WHEN ( lid.reportedcurrencycodeiso IS NOT NULL 
           AND fc.iscurrencydependent = 1 
           AND lid.statementcurrencycodeiso <> lid.reportedcurrencycodeiso 
           AND fc.isflowitem = 1 ) THEN 
lid.adjustedforcorporateactionvalue * 
cds.dbo.Exrate(lid.reportedcurrencycodeiso, lid.statementcurrencycodeiso, p.periodenddate) 
  WHEN ( lid.reportedcurrencycodeiso IS NOT NULL 
         AND fc.iscurrencydependent = 1 
         AND lid.statementcurrencycodeiso <> lid.reportedcurrencycodeiso 
         AND fc.isflowitem = 0 
         AND p.periodlengthunitcode = 'M' ) THEN 
  lid.adjustedforcorporateactionvalue 
* 
cds.dbo.Getaveragefxrate(lid.reportedcurrencycodeiso, lid.statementcurrencycodeiso, 
Dateadd("MONTH", -p.periodlength, p.periodenddate), p.periodenddate) 
  WHEN ( lid.reportedcurrencycodeiso IS NOT NULL 
         AND fc.iscurrencydependent = 1 
         AND lid.statementcurrencycodeiso <> lid.reportedcurrencycodeiso 
         AND fc.isflowitem = 0 
         AND p.periodlengthunitcode = 'W' ) THEN 
  lid.adjustedforcorporateactionvalue 
* 
cds.dbo.Getaveragefxrate(lid.reportedcurrencycodeiso, lid.statementcurrencycodeiso, 
Dateadd("WEEK", -p.periodlength, p.periodenddate), p.periodenddate) 
  ELSE lid.adjustedforcorporateactionvalue 
END )            AS AdjustedForCorporateActionValue, 
lid.reportedcurrencycodeiso, 
lid.xbrlelementid, 
xbrlele.xbrlelementname, 
Cast(NULL AS CHAR(3)), 
Cast(NULL AS DATETIME), 
Cast(NULL AS DATETIME), 
Cast(NULL AS CHAR(1)), 
Cast(NULL AS DATETIME), 
Cast(NULL AS SMALLINT), 
src.dcn, 
src.docformat, 
lid.asreporteditemid, 
ari.docbyteoffset, 
ari.docbytelength, 
ari.bookmark, 
ari.itemdisplayednegativeflag, 
ari.itemscalingfactor, 
ari.itemdisplayedvalue, 
ari.reportedvalue, 
ari.reporteddescription, 
ari.editeddescription, 
src.documentid, 
lid.isderived, 
lid.statementsectioncode, 
IsMissMatchPhysicalMeasureID =0, 
lid.istotal, 
lid.isexcludedfromstandardization, 
si.isdetailed    AS IsDetailedSection, 
si.ispreliminary AS IsPreliminary, 
IsCreditSection =Cast(NULL AS BIT), 
IsCreditFCC =Cast(NULL AS BIT), 
si.isproforma, 
lll.instrumentndaid, 
InterimTypeID = CASE p.periodicitycode 
                  WHEN 'A' THEN 0 
                  WHEN 'S' THEN 2 
                  WHEN 'T' THEN 3 
                  WHEN 'Q' THEN 4 
                END, 
si.isnotcomparabletopriorperiod, 
si.isfundbspecial, 
si.isderived     AS IsDerivedSI, 
lid.systemderivedtypecode 
--FBLog.tasktypeid, 
--FBLog.systemstartdatetime, 
--FBLog.issplit 
FROM   trf.dbo.lineiteminstance LID(nolock) 
       --INNER JOIN #fundbbackwardlog FBLog 
       --        ON FBLog.orgid = lid.orgid 
       --           AND FBLog.periodid = lid.periodid 
       --           AND FBLog.sourceid = lid.sourceid 
       --           AND FBLog.statementtypecode = lid.statementtypecode 
       --           AND FBLog.financialsbucketid = lid.financialsbucketid 
       --           AND FBLog.statementcurrencycodeiso = 
       --               lid.statementcurrencycodeiso 
       --           AND lid.asreporteditemid IS NOT NULL 
       --           AND lid.lineiteminstanceasreporteditemid IS NULL 
       INNER JOIN trf.dbo.statementinstance SI(nolock) 
               ON lid.orgid = si.orgid 
                  AND lid.periodid = si.periodid 
                  AND lid.sourceid = si.sourceid 
                  AND lid.statementtypecode = si.statementtypecode 
                  AND lid.financialsbucketid = si.financialsbucketid 
                  AND lid.statementcurrencycodeiso = si.statementcurrencycodeiso 
       INNER JOIN trf.dbo.period P(nolock) 
               ON lid.orgid = p.orgid 
                  AND lid.periodid = p.periodid 
       INNER JOIN trf.dbo.lineitem LLL(nolock) 
               ON lll.orgid = lid.orgid 
                  AND lll.lineitemid = lid.lineitemid 
       INNER JOIN trf.dbo.financialconcept FC(nolock) 
               ON lll.financialconceptidglobal = fc.financialconceptid 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN trf.dbo.xbrlelement XBRLEle(nolock) 
                    ON lid.xbrlelementid = xbrlele.xbrlelementid 
       INNER JOIN trf.dbo.asreportedinstance ARI(nolock) 
               ON lid.orgid = ari.orgid 
                  AND lid.sourceid = ari.sourceid 
                  AND lid.asreporteditemid = ari.asreporteditemid 
       INNER JOIN trf.dbo.[source] SRC(nolock) 
               ON src.orgid = ari.orgid 
                  AND src.sourceid = ari.sourceid 
WHERE  ari.reportedvalue IS NOT NULL --AND SRC.DCN > ''         --AND SRC.DocFormat > ''         --AND ARI.BookMark > ''
```

Comment: Does it matter if your query returns [incorrect results due to NOLOCK hints](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2007/02/01/previously-committed-rows-might-be-missed-if-nolock-hint-is-used.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove functions called in the query like : **Exrate()** and **Getaveragefxrate()**.

Also change the case statement, where you are using subquery as following.

In the end of the query, use

```
left outer join trf.lineitemfundbdescription lifd 
    on lll.orgid = lifd.orgid and lll.lineitemid = lifd.lineitemid
```

and then the case will be changed to

```
case
    when lifd.orgid is null then lll.lineitemname
    else lifd.lineitemshortdescription End As LineItemName
```

It will fine tune your query to a level and gives you a correct execution plan and advice accordingly.

Remember that execution plan does not show the plan of user defined functions called with in the query.